# Is there any benefit in using PHP comments over HTML comments in HTML code?

Tags: php, html, comments

I heard someone say that there is, so I was wondering.

HTML comment:

```
<!-- Comment goes here. -->
```

PHP comment:

```
<?php // Comment goes here. ?>
```

Comment: It probably goes without saying, but there is **no** benefit for using PHP comments in actual HTML documents.  What you are asking about is how to add comments to HTML *markup* embedded in **PHP code**.

Comment: Such comments normally go to the end of the line. Does it actually look for "`?>`" or will it be part of the comment? Is there defined behaviour in this case (not a rhetorical question)?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Unlike HTML comments, PHP comments don't show up in the final output. That is often desirable, as comments are usually internal notes that are none of anybody's business.

Comment: In addition, it will speed your download times!

Comment: @DMoney ~ Yeah, so will not having comments. What's your point? Hmm...

Comment: @jcolebrand, I was saying the PHP comments will not be included with the HTML sent to the client browser, so the time to download the content will be faster.

Comment: You really didn't change anything about what I asked. I knew that's what you were saying.

Comment: @jcolebrand the point is that it allows you to have the comments, thus keeping clarity when reading the code, without having clients download the comments, thus keeping download sizes small.  Not having comments stops the code from being readable (and doesn't offer dramatic speed improvements over php comments)

Comment: @D-Money lmao, just minify the HTML output.

Comment: @Tuskan360 - Well said. 
seriousdev - True, minifing will reduce download time, but it will always be more than nothing.

Answer (score 26):

PHP comments will not be visible in the source on the client, where HTML comments will. So the question is: do you want the comment to be readable by the end user?

Comment: Caveat: potentially, the "end user" could be a front-end developer or designer, who sees the generated HTML but not the PHP code.

Answer (score 11):

PHP comments do not show up in the output HTML as other users have stated. This has two main effects:

1. The PHP comments are hidden from the end user. This has already been covered... And,
2. The PHP comments don't get sent over the Internet. This will result in a bit of a performance boost for the end user. The benefit of this is of course dependent on your verbosity.

Comment: While I agree with your #2 reason, I doubt that "it not negligible" in most cases. Unless your pages are very simplistic, the %tage of comments to HTML will be very small *in most cases*.

Comment: Fixed. I guess what I should have said is that creating PHP comments has a negligible impact on the preprocessor but _could potentially_ have some benefit for download speeds.....

Answer (score 3):

Small HTML comments can be useful for front-end developers, for example specifying the identifier of a closing tag in large files:

```
<div id="container">
    ... Hundreds or thousands of lines of HTML
</div> <!-- #container -->
```

These comments can be *extremely* helpful, and have little or no effect on the page size.

PHP comments should be kept to a minimum in your display code, because there shouldn't be an awful lot of PHP to comment (although this is an entirely different subject).

It goes without saying that you should only ever comment PHP with PHP comments, and HTML with HTML comments. If you ever find yourself having to write long HTML comments to explain some quirky HTML to your front-end developers, it's probably a bad sign.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you are commenting. In addition to all other answers, I've something that can really matter. From time to time, we coders would need to comment out a block of code like:

```
<?php foreach ($results) { ?>
  <div>
    ... more divs ...
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Assume that length of `$results` is 20 and character length of each div is around 500 bytes (a moderately dense div). Then we have 10 KB of HTML here. In this case, the two commenting methods would be very, very different:

```
<?php /* foreach ($results) { ?>
  <div>
    ... more divs ...
  </div>
<?php } */ ?>
```

Zero bytes is sent to the visitor and there isn't any PHP processing.

vs

```
<!-- <?php foreach ($results) { ?>
  <div>
    ... more divs ...
  </div>
<?php } ?> -->
```

10 KB is still sent to the visitor and PHP runs this huge-y loop for nothing.

Of course, if you are using a revision control system (for example, [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) or [Subversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion)), such comments (comments that cover running code rather than descriptions) should really be deleted altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes HTML comments are useful when you need to get information that cannot be rendered in HTML by the browser.

For example, you need to know the server's IP address that sent the HTML page, you cannot show in the HTML page... you print it as an HTML comment, so you can check that information in the HTML source code.

Comment: Why can't you render it in HTML?

Comment: obviously coz you don't want the final user to see it. it's like a blind echo, you can use it for a temporary debug and not disturb the production environment.

Comment: Ah, so you don't really mean "cannot" but "shall not". But my question was really... why can't you show the server's IP? The user knows it anyway. And putting it in a comment doesn't actually hide it from anyone.

Comment: 1) it does not modify html rendering, so the page looks like it is. and not with some ugly trace causing the customer to call you like "what's happening in here"

Comment: 2) more than 90% percent of web users have never used "View source code"

Comment: sometimes you need to change someting quickly on a production server live, this is a good manner to show info for a moment and the user does not notice anything. it's easy, don't know what you don't understand besides my bad english.

Comment: do you push ctrl+u and review the code on each web you land on?? I don't think so

Comment: No, but you _can_, so if this information is somehow "secret" then this is a pretty poor way to do it.

Comment: And you should never "change something quickly on a production server". Madness that way lies.

Comment: nobody said that the information is secret; information is not secret but has to be UI non-intrusive

Comment: That was your implication. :(

Comment: imagine you have to know the value of a server side variable. you put an html comment, watch the value, and then remove the value.

Comment: sometimes your not responsible for how productions servers are set. and don't have a repository for it. but this is another discussion besides the utility of using an html comment in some debuggin situations.

Comment: If you do not have version control or any sort of release control on your production server, then that is _absolutely_ your responsibility.

Comment: "you cannot show in the html page" as you say should be "you shall not show..." coz UI regards.

Comment: "If you do not have version control or any sort of release control on your production server, then that is absolutely your responsibility." they are not my production servers, and the sys admin is responsible for that, not the programmer. but as i said this is no concern at all with html comments